# Can't Connect to Docker container within local network

Tags: docker

Trying to run QuakeJS within the docker container. I'm new to docker (and networking). Couldn't connect. Decided to start easier and ran `nginxdemos/helloworld`. Still can't connect to the server (running Ubuntu Server).

Tried:
`docker run -d -p 8080:80 nginxdemos/hello`

Probably relevant `ip addr`:

```
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:03:73:be:70:eb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s25
    inet 10.89.233.61/20 metric 100 brd 10.89.239.255 scope global dynamic eno1
       valid_lft 27400sec preferred_lft 27400sec
    inet6 fe80::1a03:73ff:febe:70eb/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:7c:bb:47 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe7c:bb47/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Here's docker-network-ls:

```
NETWORK ID     NAME       DRIVER    SCOPE

5671ad4b57fe   bridge     bridge    local

a9348e40fb3c   host       host      local

fdb16382afbd   none       null      local
```

`ufw-status`

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   172.17.0.0/16 on docker0
```

But when I try to access in a web browser (chrome and firefox) at 172.17.0.0:8080 (or many other permutations) I just end up in a time out. I'm sure this is a stupid think but I'm very stuck.

**UPDATE**

I installed a basic apache server and it worked fine. So it's something with Docker. I think.

**UPDATE AGAIN**

`docker ps`

`CONTAINER ID   IMAGE              COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS             PORTS                                   NAMES a7bbfee83954   nginxdemos/hello   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, :::8080->80/tcp   relaxed_morse`

I can use `curl localhost:8080` and see the nginx page

I was playing with ufw but disabled it, not worried about network security. Tried ufw-docker too

***FINAL UPDATE***

Restarting Docker worked :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you publish a port with the `-p` option to `docker run`, the syntax is `-p <host port>:<container port>`, and you are saying, "expose the service running in the container on port `<container port>` on the Docker host as port `<host port>`.".

So when you run:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 nginxdemos/hello
```

You could open a browser on your host and connect to http://localhost:8080 (because port `8080` is the `<host_port>`). If you have the address of the container, you could *also* connect to `http://<container_ip>:80`, but you almost never want to do that, because every time you start a new container it receives a new ip address.

We publish ports to the host so that we don't need to muck about finding container ip address.

---

> running 172.17.0.0:8080 (0.1, 0.2) or 10.89.233.61:8080 result in a timeout

`172.17.0.0:8080` doesn't make any sense.

Both `172.17.0.1:8080` and `10.89.233.61:8080` ought to work (as should any other address assigned to a host interface). Some diagnostics to try:

- Is the container actually running (`docker ps`)?
- On the docker host are you able to connect to `localhost:8080`?
- It looks like you're using UFW. Have you made any recent changes to the firewall?
- If you restart docker (`systemctl restart docker`), do you see any changes in behavior?

Comment: Ok but lets say I want access said port on a different computer (albeit one on the same network)? Shouldn't `http://<container_ip>:80` work on a different computer?

Comment: The answer is the same: you would connect to port `8080` on your host. So if your computer is `10.89.233.61` on your local network, other machines on your network could access http://10.89.233.61:8080 (assuming that you don't have firewall rules that prevent this access).

Comment: Right! But running `172.17.0.0:8080` (0.1, 0.2) or `10.89.233.61:8080` result in a timeout. So I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Resetting docker worked. Marking as correct, thank you